# Install app from TestFlight suddenly meet "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." error

Tags: ios, testing, functional-testing

I cannot install app from TestFlight, when I try to install it,"A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." error occurs in log.

This issue suddenly happened, what is may cause this error? My TestFlight account suddenly expired?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether your bundle id matches to your provisional profile. Also check whether the provisional profile added is a developer provisional profile and it is active in iTunesconnect.

Thank you